# Multiple linear regressions by factor in ggplot r

Tags: r, ggplot2, linear-regression, scatter-plot

I would like to make 1 scatterplot with variables of different depths, and add individual linear regressions to each depth group. I'm struggling with the code in ggplot.

Here is the dput of my data (called "ro_aue"):

```
    structure(list(sample_id = 64:77, site = structure(1:14, .Label = c("ROA1-0", 
    "ROA1-30", "ROA1-60", "ROA1-90", "ROA2-0", "ROA2-30", "ROA3-0", 
    "ROA3-30", "ROA3-60", "ROA3-90", "ROA4-0", "ROA4-30", "ROA4-60", 
    "ROA4-90"), class = "factor"), field = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "RO", class = "factor"), 
        hole_number = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "ROA", class = "factor"), 
        depth = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
        4L, 4L), co2_flux_µmol_c_m2_s1 = c(154.3338436, 282.1015066, 
        465.7342506, 554.0064102, 133.6499023, 300.5398639, 143.2820904, 
        379.3802332, 331.9730719, 265.3653557, 116.5290758, 417.7642772, 
        303.2152718, 409.3601595), soc_stock_kg_m2 = c(4.7, 2.5, 
        2.5, 0.3, 5.5, 2.2, 3.4, 1.8, 1, 0.4, 3.4, 0.6, 0.7, 0.6)), .Names = c("sample_id", 
    "site", "field", "hole_number", "depth", "co2_flux_µmol_c_m2_s1", 
    "soc_stock_kg_m2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -14L
    ))
```

using this code, I'm able to get a nice scatterplot:

```
    ggplot(data = ro_aue, aes(x = soc_stock_kg_m2, y = co2_flux_µmol_c_m2_s1)) +
      geom_point(size = 4, aes(color = factor(depth), shape = factor(depth))) +
      labs(x = lab_soc, y = lab_co2) +
      labs(color=legend_title, shape=legend_title) +
      ggtitle(expression('Rottenbuch Hole Campaign, CO'[2]*'')) + 
      geom_smooth(method=lm, se=FALSE, formula=y~x-1)
```

[image: what I have]

But what I really need is something like this:

[image: what I need]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You want the color aesthetic to apply to `geom_smooth`, so either put `color = factor(depth)` in the main ggplot call or add it inside `aes` in `geom_smooth`.

Comment: Oh my gosh. That was a quick, easy fix. THANK YOU. But now the linear regression lines are very short. Do you know how to force the regression through zero?

Comment: Your `lab_soc`, `lab_co2` and `legend_title` variables are not included in `ro_aue`

Comment: Also, the dataset you provided does not produce the same plot you have here. Please either update the data, or the plots

Comment: `fullrange = TRUE` might help with the line length.